# How to correctly break a long line in Python?

Tags: python

How would I go about breaking the following line? The [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) guideline doesn't make it very clear to me.

```
confirmation_message = _('ORDER_CREATED: %(PROPERTY_1)s - %(PROPERTY_2)s - %(PROPERTY_3)s - %(PROPERTY_4)s')  % {'PROPERTY_1': order.lorem, 'PROPERTY_2': order.ipsum, 'PROPERTY_4': order.dolor, 'PROPERTY_5': order.sit}
```

Comment: Are you intentionally leaving the `order` outside of the call to `_`, so that they aren't translated?

Comment: The code was modified and simplified for the question. In reality the variables are also translated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One would typically do something like:

```
confirmation_message = _(
    'ORDER_CREATED: %(PROPERTY_1)s - '
    '%(PROPERTY_2)s - %(PROPERTY_3)s - %(PROPERTY_4)s') % {
        'PROPERTY_1': order.lorem,
        'PROPERTY_2': order.ipsum,
        'PROPERTY_3': order.ipsum,
        'PROPERTY_4': order.dolor,
        'PROPERTY_5': order.sit
    }
```

This takes advantage of the fact that adjacent strings (`'like ' 'this'`) are concatenated to shorten the long line of text; everything else is split on commas.

Comment: This is pretty much what [yapf](https://github.com/google/yapf) would give you, although yapf won't break the string up like that.

Answer (score 6):

```
confirmation_message = (
    _(
        'ORDER_CREATED: %(PROPERTY_1)s - %(PROPERTY_2)s - '
        '%(PROPERTY_3)s - %(PROPERTY_4)s'
    ) % {
        'PROPERTY_1': order.lorem,
        'PROPERTY_2': order.ipsum,
        'PROPERTY_4': order.dolor,
        'PROPERTY_5': order.sit,
    })
```

Or also:

```
confirmation_message_tmpl = _(
    'ORDER_CREATED: %(PROPERTY_1)s - %(PROPERTY_2)s - '
    '%(PROPERTY_3)s - %(PROPERTY_4)s'
)
confirmation_message = confirmation_message_tmpl % {
    'PROPERTY_1': order.lorem,
    'PROPERTY_2': order.ipsum,
    'PROPERTY_4': order.dolor,
    'PROPERTY_5': order.sit,
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There's not much point in using a dictionary *literal* as the right-hand argument of the `%`. It takes up a lot of space without really enhancing the readability of your code.

```
confirmation_message = _('ORDER_CREATED: %s - %s - %s - %s') % (
    order.lorem, 
    order.ipsum, 
    order.dolor,
    order.sit
)
```

The `operator.attrgetter` function is useful here:

```
import operator
attrs = operator.attrgetter('lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit')
confirmation_message = _('ORDER_CREATED: %s - %s - %s - %s') % attrs(order)
```

If you can, switch to using the `format` method:

```
msg_template = 'ORDER_CREATED: {0.lorem} - {0.ipsum} - {0.dolor} - {0.sit}'
confirmation_message = _(msg_template).format(order)
```

Comment: I have to use it like that so that the persons doing the translation for the application knows what field is what in case that some language requires some weird positioning of the variables inside the string

Comment: @yoshi - Wouldn't the `confirmation_message = _(msg_template).format(order)` method both accomplish the same thing and be more readable?  Unless the `dict` method is a project requirement/standard?

Comment: @yoshi To change the order you're better off using new-style formating either like `'ORDER_CREATED: {0} - {1} - {2} - {3}'` or using the last option chepner gave. Writing `PROPERTY_` before each just obscures what's happening. If you really hate new style formatting, at least do `'ORDER_CREATED: %(0)s - %(1)s - %(2)s - %(3)s'`.

Comment: @Veedrac Those names are just for the example in this question, in reality PROPERTY_1 is ORDER_ID, PROPERTY_2 is PRICE, etc. I didn't add the real variable names because they're irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @yoshi Given that you've massively changed the length of the string and the validity of certain answers (eg. chepner's), hiding the real names was probably a bad call.

Comment: @Veedrac Some names were longer, some names were shorter but the overall length was roughly the same. How would that change the validity of the answer? The accepted solution worked very well.

Comment: @yoshi Do you not see how 2/3 of chepner's answers were invalidated? Or the fact that my suggestions were invalidated? I had other suggestions, which were also invalidated, and the way you phrased it also prevented me from suggesting other valid things (such as `_(templ).format(order_id=..., price=..., ...)`).

Comment: @Veedrac None of my answers or your suggestions are invalidated just because the actual property names are different than posted. At worst, short names just make the issue of trying to split the line less urgent. The accepted answer is fine; I upvoted it.

Comment: @Veedrac Nothing was invalidated, it was just a difference of variable names with a few characters plus or minus. What relevance is there if it was PROPERTY_1 vs ORDER_ID or PROPERTY_2 vs ORDER_PRICE? The answers work just fine on both the real code and the code in the question, chill out.

Comment: @yoshi Sorry if I came across as angry (I'm not). I do disagree, but I'm not going to push the matter further.

Answer (score 2):

The way you'd probably see this broken up the most often is using [implicit line joining](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#implicit-line-joining), similar to this:

```
confirmation_message = (_('ORDER_CREATED: %(PROPERTY_1)s - %(PROPERTY_2)s - '
                          '%(PROPERTY_3)s - %(PROPERTY_4)s')  %
                        {'PROPERTY_1': order.lorem, 'PROPERTY_2': order.ipsum,
                         'PROPERTY_4': order.dolor, 'PROPERTY_5': order.sit})
```

[Implicit line joining](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#implicit-line-joining) means that:

> Expressions in parentheses, square brackets or curly braces can be split
>   over more than one physical line without using backslashes.

The problem with explicit joining using the `\` character is that an extra character (like a space) at the end of the physical line after the `\` will cause an error, like so:

```
>>> c = '1 2 3 4 5 6 ' \  # This will generate an error.
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    c = '1 2 3 4 5 6 ' \  # This will generate an error.
                                                       ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
>>>
```

This doesn't happen with implicit joining:

```
>>> c = ('1 2 3 4 5 6 ' # No error.
...      '7 8 9 10')
>>> print(c)
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
>>>
```